# Jsoup always return timeout error

Tags: timeout, jsoup

I have the following code to get the tock price from yahoo finance.hk
But it always return time out error
please help

```
  public GetStockPriceFromWebOneByOne(String url){
        this.url = url;
    }

     private void setDataFromAAStock() throws IOException, InterruptedException{
        Document document = Jsoup.connect(url).ignoreHttpErrors(true).timeout(timeOut*1000).get();  // s
        //TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(2);
        Elements answerers = document.select("div.yfi_rt_quote_summary div.yfi_rt_quote_summary_rt_top.sigfig_promo_0  span.time_rtq_ticker");
       // Elements answerers = document.select(".content .inline_block.vat.float_l .boxForex .font26 .neg .arr_ud.arrow_d6");
        for (Element answerer : answerers) {
            //System.out.print(answerer.text()+"\n");
            price = answerer.text();
           // splitString(answerer.text());
        }
    }

    public String getDataFromAAStock() throws IOException, InterruptedException{
        setDataFromAAStock();
        return price;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I did not check with yahoo finance hk, but you maybe should try to set a plausible browser userAgent string when connecting to it. See the [docs](https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/Connection.html#userAgent-java.lang.String-)

```
Document document = Jsoup.connect(url)
                         .ignoreHttpErrors(true)
                         .timeout(timeOut*1000)
                         .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; WindowsNT 5.1; en-US; rv1.8.1.6) Gecko/20070725 Firefox/2.0.0.6")
```

*Addendum:*
Of course, you can turn off the timeout altogether by using:

```
Document document = Jsoup.connect(url)
                         .ignoreHttpErrors(true)
                         .timeout(0)
```

Did you look at the network traffic between the browser and the site with the browser developer tools? It might help you to analyze the underlying problem.

Comment: I have tried to use userAgent and not use userAgent  methods, both not wroks

Comment: @WaiHung see my modified answer

Answer (score 0):

I would split the

```
Document document = Jsoup.connect(url).ignoreHttpErrors(true).timeout(timeOut*1000).get();
```

into

```
Connection connect = Jsoup.connect(url)
                     .ignoreHttpErrors(true)
                     .timeout(timeOut*1000);

                     // use this for chrome
                     .userAgent("Mozilla");

System.out.println("Connection made BEFORE document.");
Document document = connect.get();
System.out.println("Connection made AFTER document.");
```

I think there is an issue with your "Connection" because of the `.get()` which may need a `.userAgent("Mozilla");` BEFORE you call `.get();`.